# How to handle WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable

Tags: python, selenium

I have a web-**scraper** which I am running via windows task scheduler, it sometimes crashes in between which prevents the scheduler from restarting the script therefore I put all of my script inside try-except block so that my script doesn't crashes. In except block I am closing and quitting driver to avoid multiple instances of the browsers.
The problem is sometimes in except block I receive the error "Message: chrome not reachable". I suspect the problem is that I dont have a browser/driver instance running and I am trying to close it.
[image]

Line 295 of bot.py is inside except block:
[image]

How can I handle this exception so that the script crashes forcefully instead it reaches Line 298.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead, [edit] the question to include the code as plain text in a code block.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably try to solve this problem by only running driver.close and driver.quit if the browser is still open.  You can write a function to find if the browser is open or not, something like this

```
import httplib
import socket

from selenium.webdriver.remote.command import Command

def get_status(driver):
    try:
        driver.execute(Command.STATUS)
        return "Alive"
    except (socket.error, httplib.CannotSendRequest):
        return "Dead"
```

Then, (obviously) use

```
// code here
if get_status(driver) = "Alive":
   driver.close()
   driver.quit()

// other code
```